# How can I make UITextView resize on orientation change?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator, uitextview

So I decided to make an iOS app. I have started with something simple which is a web browser.
Surprisingly im finding it quite easy to get a grasp on but I have now come across something I can't figure out.

My application looks fine in Landscape which can be seen below:

[Landscape](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7923805/apps/StackOverflow/Landscape.png)

but when I change the orientation of my device it looks messy because the UITextField doesn't resize, shown below:

[Portrait](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7923805/apps/StackOverflow/Portrait.png)

Does anyone know of a (noob friendly) way of doing this?

Thanks,
Ashley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the autosizing on here:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling